# Preserve leading whitespaces in commit message bodies (GitLab)

Tags: gitlab

(see also [the same issue in Redmine](https://superuser.com/q/1815877/563952))

`git log` correctly displays indentation and alignment created by inserting leading whitespaces:

```
Do some cool stuff

class CoolStuffCapable
+ function doSomeCoolStuff does cool stuff
  ? beware of uncool limitations I need to fix later
    ? soonGettingSolved will be fixed within the current major release
    ? longLongWithUs will remain until at least the next major release
  ? there is a precondition I cannot get rid of
? moved field BoringStuffCapable::notSoInternalState to fix Feature Envy
  ? renamed to reallyInternalState accordingly
- constant MAYBE_UNUSED was unused

refs #1
```

gitlab-ce:16.3.4-ce.0 trims these whitespaces, even though it puts commit messages into `<pre>` tags that would support leading whitespaces:

```
Do some cool stuff

class CoolStuffCapable
+ function doSomeCoolStuff does cool stuff
? beware of uncool limitations I need to fix later
? soonGettingSolved will be fixed within the current major release
? longLongWithUs will remain until at least the next major release
? there is a precondition I cannot get rid of
? moved field BoringStuffCapable::notSoInternalState to fix Feature Envy
? renamed to reallyInternalState accordingly
- constant MAYBE_UNUSED was unused

refs #1
```

Notably, it does this **only within Merge requests** - when viewing individual commits, it displays the leading whitespaces correctly.

That is:

- `<GitLab url>/<Project>/-/commit/<hash>` displays fine
- `<GitLab url>/<Project>/-/merge_requests/<request Id>/diffs?commit_id=<hash>` omits trailing whitespaces

Can I make it display the correct message *everywhere?*

(The given version is the *minimal* version I can use. Updating to a later version is fine.)

Comment: Note on previous research: Searching for relevant documentation is very hard, because somehow search engines substitute "trailing" for "leading" and of course a lot of questions ask about _trimming_ whitespaces, not about _not trimming_ . My Google Fu was too weak to find anything remotely relevant.

Comment: Seems to be reported here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/402697 You can mark it to receive notifications after logging in to GitLab.com and/or leave a thumbs up on it to bump it up in visibility.